# Process Designer Unable to login to Process Center

Tags: business-process-management, bpmn, ibm-bpm

IBM BPM 8.5.5 install on Linux
Process Designer installed on Windows 7

New to BPM, but completed the following:

1) Installed IBM BPM 8.5.5
2) Logged into Process Center and created a new user account.
3) Installed Process Designer on Windows 7

When Process Designer is started I enter the new user account created in Process Center.  After a period of time the login attempt fails with the following details in the .log file.

```
!SESSION 2015-04-30 17:30:42.041 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 7 x86-32 20131230_180580 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580
J9CL - 20131230_180580
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -dir ltr
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -dir ltr -clean

!ENTRY teamworks.ae.product 1 0 2015-04-30 17:30:45.787
!MESSAGE [InteractiveSplashHandler] Starting Authoring Environment. Bundle: teamworks.ae.product Version: 8.5.5.0 BPMRepo Prefix: http://172.18.15.85:9080
!SESSION 2015-04-30 17:32:17.807 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 7 x86-32 20131230_180580 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580
J9CL - 20131230_180580
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -dir ltr
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -dir ltr -clean

!ENTRY teamworks.ae.product 1 0 2015-04-30 17:32:21.257
!MESSAGE [InteractiveSplashHandler] Starting Authoring Environment. Bundle: teamworks.ae.product Version: 8.5.5.0 BPMRepo Prefix: http://172.18.15.85:9080

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 2 0 2015-04-30 17:32:35.183
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfig] CWPKI0041W: One or more key stores are using the default password.

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:32:35.204
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager] CWPKI0027I: Disabling default hostname verification for HTTPS URL connections.

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:32:56.784
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:32:56.787
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:33:17.795
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:33:17.802
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:33:38.812
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:33:38.818
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 2 0 2015-04-30 17:33:59.821
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.bpm.ejbproxy.rest.EJBProxyRestHelper callEJB] Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:34:21.823
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:34:21.830
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:34:42.838
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:34:42.845
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:35:03.855
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:35:03.863
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 2 0 2015-04-30 17:35:24.867
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.bpm.ejbproxy.rest.EJBProxyRestHelper callEJB] Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:35:47.877
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:35:47.884
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:36:08.896
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:36:08.903
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:36:29.902
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:36:29.904
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 2 0 2015-04-30 17:36:50.908
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.bpm.ejbproxy.rest.EJBProxyRestHelper callEJB] Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:14.912
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:14.915
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:35.923
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:35.930
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:56.936
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:37:56.997
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-04-30 17:38:04.640
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getDisplay(Widget.java:582)
    at teamworks.ae.product.splash.InteractiveSplashHandler.doEventLoop(InteractiveSplashHandler.java:329)
    at teamworks.ae.product.splash.InteractiveSplashHandler.init(InteractiveSplashHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2456)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at teamworks.ae.product.TWApplication.start(TWApplication.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-04-30 17:38:04.658
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate splash
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getDisplay(Widget.java:582)
    at teamworks.ae.product.splash.InteractiveSplashHandler.doEventLoop(InteractiveSplashHandler.java:329)
    at teamworks.ae.product.splash.InteractiveSplashHandler.init(InteractiveSplashHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2456)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at teamworks.ae.product.TWApplication.start(TWApplication.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:04.877
!MESSAGE [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh] Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e02dc168: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e02dc168]; startup date [Thu Apr 30 17:38:04 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:04.916
!MESSAGE [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [registry.xml]

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:05.004
!MESSAGE [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory] Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e02dc168]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@97ac3e97

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:05.060
!MESSAGE [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@97ac3e97: defining beans [registry,twConfiguration,ejbDelegate.CommonServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.ExportImportServiceDelegate,ejbDelegate.PersistenceServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.PKGeneratorDelegate,ejbDelegate.HistoricalDataRetrievalServiceDelegate,ejbDelegate.AuthorizationAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDInstanceAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDInstanceCommentAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDInstanceDocumentAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDDocumentAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.RemoteDocumentAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.ReportAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.ScoreboardAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.TaskAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.BPDEngineServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.ClientServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.RepositoryServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.EventMgrDelegate,ejbDelegate.ReflectionServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.SecurityDelegate,ejbDelegate.TaskDelegate,ejbDelegate.TaskServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.EventQueueManagerDelegate,ejbDelegate.RuntimeServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.InstanceMigrationDelegate,ejbDelegate.RuntimeErrorAPIDelegate,ejbDelegate.ParticipantGroupsDelegate,ejbDelegate.AuthorizationServiceDelegate,ejbDelegate.BlueprintManagerDelegate,ejbDelegate.SecurityProviderDelegate,ejbDelegate.InternalGroupsDelegate,ejbDelegate.UserStatusServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.IBMInterchangeImpExpServiceDelegate,ejbDelegate.PALServicesDelegate,eventAdapter,ejbDelegate.RepositoryLogDelegate,ejbDelegate.ProcessCenterActionsDelegate,ejbDelegate.OSLCServicesDelegate,ejbDelegate.LinkageServicesDelegate,eventAdapterForServer,referenceResolver,snapshotHelper,contextTreeElementsLookup,contextAndTypeTreeElementsLookup,versionSummaryIdLookup,contextDependenciesLookup,cache.versionedpo,cache.unversionedpo]; root of factory hierarchy

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 2 0 2015-04-30 17:38:17.999
!MESSAGE [com.ibm.bpm.ejbproxy.rest.EJBProxyRestHelper callEJB] Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:43.004
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:38:43.007
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:39:04.014
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY teamworks.appserver.websphere 1 0 2015-04-30 17:39:04.018
!MESSAGE [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry] Retrying request
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Process Designer (PD) is not connecting properly to the Process Center.  In the folder where your Process Designer is installed is a file "eclipse.ini" open that with a text editor and take a look at it.  There should be an entry for the server you are connecting to.  It looks something like -

```
-Dcom.ibm.bpm.processcenter.url=https://MyProcessServer:9443
```

You should confirm that entry is what you expect it to be.  Check the server name and port.  If it is wrong, correct it.  Also make sure that you can ping that server name from the client, as sometimes the install is done against, say, the machine name, and not a FQDN.

If that is all correct there is a chance that a firewall is blocking other ports the client machine needs open to communicate with your Process Center.